# AS3 - Score not updating

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I have set this that when the player hits the coin, a point should be added (in fact I can see it is added trough the trace) but the textField is not updating. Did I do somthing wrong? Btw the text field is already Dynamic and I have incorporated the font.

```
coin.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, addScore);

var score:Number = 0;
scoreCounter.text = "0";

function addScore (e) {
if (objPlayer.hitTestObject(coin)) {
updateScore();
trace("Score: " + score);
coin.x = - 1 - coin.width/2;
    }
}
 function updateScore() {
    score++;
    scoreCounter.text = String(score);
}
```

I've also tried with this approach:

```
coin.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, addScore);

var score:int = 0;

function addScore (e) {
if (objPlayer.hitTestObject(coin)) {
    score++;
    updateScore();
    trace("Score: " + score);
    coin.x = - 1 - coin.width/2;
}
}
function updateScore():void {
 scoreCounter.text = ("Score: " + score);
}
```

Comment: what do you mean it looks ago in my code? I haven't added it trough code

Comment: Doesn't look like your posted code is the issue. can you post your .fla?

Comment: ok, but I'm using Flash CS6, should I save it with compatibility with CS5.5?

Comment: http://www.mediafire.com/?zmvq3zmdeeboa2b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your code is fine.  Your using a specific font (Arial), so you need to embed that font.   Or, use the **_sans** font instead.  Then it should work for you.

Comment: It worked with _sans (i usually use it, but I totally forgot about), but didn't work after embedding arial. weird.. but its working, so thakyou :)

Comment: When you embed, did you make sure the numerals or all was checked?